# Switch statement returning wrong result

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I'm trying to run through this function which takes two arguments, income and filer status, and adjusts income to the after tax value using a number of switch statements. I'm clearly making a mistake somewhere because the function consistently returns 0 instead of my expected result.

```
    var afterTaxes = function(income, filer) {
    var adjusted = 0;
    if (filer === "single") {
        switch (income) {
            case income < 9325:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.10) * income;
                break;
            case income < 37950:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.15) * income;
                break;
            case income < 91900:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.25) * income;
                break;
            case income < 191650:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.33) * income;
                break;
            case income < 416700:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.35) * income;
                break;
            case income >= 416700:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.40) * income;
                break;
            };
    } else if (filer === "married") {
        var adjusted = 0;
        switch (income) {
            case income < 9325:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.10) * income;
                break;
            case income < 37950:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.15) * income;
                break;
            case income < 91900:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.25) * income;
                break;
            case income < 191650:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.33) * income;
                break;
            case income < 416700:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.35) * income;
                break;
            case income >= 416700:
                adjusted = (1.00 - 0.40) * income;
                break;
        };  
    };
    return adjusted;
};

afterTaxes(150000, "single");
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is JS, your switch statement is incorrect. It takes an expression see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Quick fix is to change the statements to `switch(true){...}`

Comment: Ah thanks. You helped me figure out where I went wrong.